# Dificuldade em passar um parâmetro para um rdlc que tenho(Oracle)

Tags: c#, reportviewer, reporting-services

Não estou conseguindo passar uma parâmetro para o meu relatório. Tenho um campo chamado de Regulamentado, referente ao campo Ind_Regulamentado. veja o código abaixo e como eu faço esse filtro?

```
public static void Emitir()
        {           
            //Relatório com DataSource = ORACLE
            dsPlanoMedico.PLANO_MEDICODataTable dtPlanoMedico = new dsPlanoMedico.PLANO_MEDICODataTable();
            dsPlanoMedicoTableAdapters.PLANO_MEDICOTableAdapter adapt = new dsPlanoMedicoTableAdapters.PLANO_MEDICOTableAdapter();

            adapt.Fill(dtPlanoMedico);
            dtPlanoMedico.Where(i => i.IND_REGULAMENTADO == "S");//aqui não funciona

            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dsDados", dtPlanoMedico.DefaultView);
            ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();

            viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "ReportBD.rdlc";
            //viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("Regulamentado", "S"));
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            string encoding = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;

            byte[] bytesPDF = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            FileStream fsPDF = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\report.pdf", FileMode.Create);
            fsPDF.Write(bytesPDF, 0, bytesPDF.Length);
            fsPDF.Close();
            fsPDF.Dispose();

            byte[] bytesExcel = viewer.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            FileStream fsExcel = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\report.xls", FileMode.Create);
            fsExcel.Write(bytesExcel, 0, bytesExcel.Length);
            fsExcel.Close();
            fsExcel.Dispose();

            byte[] bytesWord = viewer.LocalReport.Render("Word", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            FileStream fsWord = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\report.doc", FileMode.Create);
            fsWord.Write(bytesWord, 0, bytesWord.Length);
            fsWord.Close();
            fsWord.Dispose();


        }
```

Fui fazer umas alterações e começou a me dar um erro:
essas foram as alterações:

```
var dv = new System.Data.DataView(dtPlanoMedico);
            dv.RowFilter = "IND_REGULAMENTADO LIKE 'S'";

            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dsDados", dv);
```

E esse o erro:

> The Value expression for the text box ‘COD_PLANO’ refers to the field
>   ‘COD_PLANO’.   Report item expressions can only refer to fields within
>   the current dataset scope or,  if inside an aggregate, the specified
>   dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct
>   case.  C:\Projetos\Servicos\ReportBD.rdlc Servicos

O que pode ser isso?

Fiz esse filtro e filtrou: `dv.RowFilter = "IND_REGULAMENTADO LIKE 'N'";`, porem se eu faço dessa forma:

```
dv.RowFilter = "IND_REGULAMENTADO LIKE 'N'"; 
dv.RowFilter = "TIPO_REGISTRO_ANS LIKE 'D'";
```

aí só filtra pelo último e não ambos. Como eu resolvo isso?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi assim:

```
public static void Emitir()
        {
            //Relatório com DataSource = ORACLE
            dsPlanoMedico.PLANO_MEDICODataTable dtPlanoMedico = new dsPlanoMedico.PLANO_MEDICODataTable();
            dsPlanoMedicoTableAdapters.PLANO_MEDICOTableAdapter adapt = new dsPlanoMedicoTableAdapters.PLANO_MEDICOTableAdapter();

            adapt.Fill(dtPlanoMedico);
            //dtPlanoMedico.Where(i => i.IND_REGULAMENTADO == "S");

            var dv = new System.Data.DataView(dtPlanoMedico);//aqui
            dv.RowFilter = "IND_REGULAMENTADO LIKE 'N' and TIPO_REGISTRO_ANS LIKE 'D'";//aqui

            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dsDados", dv);//aqui
            ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();

            viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "ReportBD.rdlc";
            //viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("Regulamentado", "S"));
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            string encoding = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;

            byte[] bytesPDF = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            FileStream fsPDF = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\report.pdf", FileMode.Create);
            fsPDF.Write(bytesPDF, 0, bytesPDF.Length);
            fsPDF.Close();
            fsPDF.Dispose();

            byte[] bytesExcel = viewer.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            FileStream fsExcel = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\report.xls", FileMode.Create);
            fsExcel.Write(bytesExcel, 0, bytesExcel.Length);
            fsExcel.Close();
            fsExcel.Dispose();

            byte[] bytesWord = viewer.LocalReport.Render("Word", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            FileStream fsWord = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\report.doc", FileMode.Create);
            fsWord.Write(bytesWord, 0, bytesWord.Length);
            fsWord.Close();
            fsWord.Dispose();


        }
```